# Getting error 1064 in automatically-generated code from MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, schema, mysql-workbench

I have started using `mySQL workbench (Version 6.3.4.0)` and I have used the EER Diagram tool to design a schema. So far, so good. However, when I try and run the Forward Engineering, I get the error below.

> "ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'COMMENT '') ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 8"

I've not edited it at all, this is purely the automatic code.

If I remove the "COMMENT ''" from the primary key, then it runs, but it doesn't create any tables on my server.

```
-- Table `mrcatalogue2`.`Location`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mrcatalogue2`.`Location` (
  `chromosome` VARCHAR(2) NULL COMMENT '',
  `position` VARCHAR(10) NULL COMMENT '',
  `hg19_coordinates` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`hg19_coordinates`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```